# Load php image from string

Tags: php

I have a text file called `database.txt` and it contains 3 URLs separated with a " - ".

```
<?
$dir = $_POST['path123'];
$percorso = file($dir."/database.txt");
while(list(,$value) = each($percorso)){
list($gp1, $gp2, $gp3) = split("[:]", $value);
#declaration trim()
$params["gp1"] = trim($gp1);
$params["gp2"] = trim($gp2);
$params["gp3"] = trim($gp3);
#print results
}
echo '<img src="$gp1" border=0>';
?>
```

As you can see, `path123` is the name of the folder and $percorso is the path of the database.txt. With that code I should load the 3 URLs in 3 different variables (gp1, gp2 and gp3).

My problem is that when I use `echo '<img src="$gp1" border=0>'` mozilla gives me an error here that says "syntax error, unexpected $end". So I can't show on the screen the 1st URL on my database.txt file. Any help?

Comment: you didn't close your while

Comment: fixed. By the way I still can't see the image

Comment: Can you show us the resulting HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
list($gp1, $gp2, $gp3) = split("[:]", $value); //will output http://
```

to

```
list($gp1, $gp2, $gp3) = split("[-]", $value); //will output http://linkhere.tld
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
echo '<img src="$gp1" border=0>';
```

To

```
echo '<img src="'.$gp1.'" style="border: none;" />';
```